# MATLAB - XML Find sibling element

Tags: xml, matlab, xpath, siblings

I have the following XML structure:

```
<LMS>
<StressGradientCorrection>
      <Gradients>
            <Gradient>
                <Curve>
                    <Point>
                        <NormalizedGradient Value="0.01" />
                        <ReductionFactor Value="1" />
                    </Point>
                    <Point>
                        <NormalizedGradient Value="0.1" />
                        <ReductionFactor Value="1" />
                    </Point>
                    <Point>
                        <NormalizedGradient Value="1" />
                        <ReductionFactor Value="1" />
                    </Point>
                    <Point>
                        <NormalizedGradient Value="10" />
                        <ReductionFactor Value="1" />
                    </Point>
                </Curve>
            </Gradient>
        </Gradients>
    </StressGradientCorrection>
</LMS>
```

I need to change the value of each `<ReductionFactor>`, based on the value of the `<NormalizedGadient>` in the same `<Point>`. So far I can distinguish an element only based on it's atributes, like Name or Value, but here I cannot. How can I distinguish an element, based on the Value of a sibling element?

Here is the starting piece of code:

```
clear all
close all
clc

% Import the XPath classes
import javax.xml.xpath.*

% Construct the DOM.
doc = xmlread('SGC_EXAMPLE.xml');

% Creating an xPath
factory = javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance();
xpath = factory.newXPath();

Path = xpath.compile('/LMS/StressGradientCorrection/Gradients/Gradient/Curve/Point/NormalizedGradient[@Value="0.01"]');
List = Path.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
Sibling = List.item(0);

% YOUR PROPOSAL HERE

MyNewlyFoundVariable.setAttribute('Value','5')

xmlwrite('Final.xml',doc);
```

So far I just know how to find the sibling based on it's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the following sibling like this :

```
/LMS/StressGradientCorrection/Gradients/Gradient/Curve/Point/NormalizedGradient[@Value="0.01"]/following-sibling::ReductionFactor/@Value
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. You just coppied one of the errors I made in the initial post: "=" instead of "=="